# NullPointerException on super.onStart()

Tags: android, youtube-api

Currently I'm writing Fragment that extends custom SherlockFragment that extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment. Unfortunately, app crashes.

CODE:

```
    public static class YouTubeVideo extends SherlockYouTubeFragment
         implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{
private TextView titleview;
private TextView descview;
private TextView countview;
private TextView timeview;
private Bundle data;

 private YouTubePlayer ytp;
private String title;
private String id;
private String desc;
private String count;
private String time;
private int timeint;
private int timem;
private int times;
private Tracker myTracker;
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    data = getArguments();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtubeview, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
     titleview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.title);
     descview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.descriptiontext);
     countview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.viewcounttext);
     timeview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.timetext);

     title = data.getString("title");
     id = data.getString("id");
     desc = data.getString("description");
     count = data.getString("viewcount");
     time = data.getString("time");
     EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this.getActivity());
     myTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance().getTracker();
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
             .beginTransaction();

     YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
      fragment.initialize(ID, this);
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.youtubeplayer, fragment);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
  titleview.setText(title);
  descview.setText(desc);
  countview.setText(count);
  try {
      timeint = Integer.parseInt(time);
      timem = timeint/60;
      times = timeint - (timem*60);      
  } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // Handle parse error.
  }
  if (times<10){
timeview.setText(String.valueOf(timem)+":0"+String.valueOf(times));
 }
  else{
      timeview.setText(String.valueOf(timem)+":"+String.valueOf(times));
  }
  super.onStart();
 }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
  Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Uruchamianie filmu nie powiodło się", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,boolean wasrestored) {
  ytp = player;
  player.addFullscreenControlFlag(4);
  if(ytp !=null){
        ytp.loadVideo(id);
       }
 }
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.video_menu, menu);
     mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();
     mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

     return true;
 }
 private Intent createShareIntent() {
     myTracker.trackEvent("videoview", "share", title + id, (long) 3);

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title + " - http://ignastv.tk/id/" + id);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sendIntent);
    return sendIntent;
}

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     int itemId = item.getItemId();

        if(itemId == R.id.vidsite){
            myTracker.trackEvent("videoview", "open-in", title + id, (long) 3);
            Intent govideo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            govideo.setData(Uri.parse(id));
            startActivity(govideo);
            return true;}

        else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

}

}
```

What is most interesting is that LogCat shows there's NullPointerException that happens in line:

```
    super.onStart();
```

Here's LogCat:

```
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706): java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onStart(Unknown Source)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at com.app.app.MainActivity$YouTubeVideo.onStart(MainActivity.java:519)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1332)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:906)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    04-27 20:19:30.055: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: have you tried to put super.onStart(); at the end of the function or after initializing your fragment?

Comment: Have you tried moving the call to `initialize` before the transaction commit?

Comment: @MitchBukaner: Yes. It doesn't work.

Comment: @dmon: Yes. It doesn't work.

Comment: what happens if you dont call super? does it crash, or displayes nothing? if you call super in different line, does the error change?

Comment: hold on, this is a fragment that "Extends" the other fragment? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @MitchBukaner If I don't call super, I get error that there's no super. If I call it in different line, it doesn't change.

Comment: @dmon: Well, YouTubePlayer extends custom SherlockFragment class that extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment class. As far as I know there is no other way to launch YouTubePlayerView in Fragment while using Action Bar Sherlock.

Comment: I think you should post the whole code. It's hard to really see what's going on just from the `onStart()`. The problem seems to be in *how* you're trying to extend the fragment. I'm confused because, if you're really extending `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`, then there's no reason for you to be creating a new instance of it in your `onStart`.

Comment: @dmon: I have to initialise `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` to run it. It is extended, so I am able to use it.

Comment: Did you include `com.google.android.youtube` as a package/lib in your project?

Comment: What's `SherlockYouTubeFragment`?

Comment: @dmon: Custom `SherlockFragment` that extends `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` to use YouTube Android Player API.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear in the SDK but as far as I was able to work it out, you don't extend YouTubePlayerFragment. You simply include the fragment in your layout (it works as a nested fragment too).

Basically you have two alternatives:

- extend YouTubeBaseActivity and inflate a layout which includes a YouTubePlayerView - it works but you can't use Fragments
- Use your favourite Activity and inflate a layout which includes the YouTubePlayerFragment. **Do not extend it**.

I have successfully added the YoutubePlayerFragment as a nested fragment too (update: this causes some memory leaks so you might prefer to avoid it). You can add other components around the YouTubePlayerFragment but be careful as the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) say you can't overlay this view with other view while the video is playing.

So, to solve your problem don't extend YouTubePlayerFragment, simply include it in your layout. By calling initialize on this fragment you will get a YouTubePlayer in the callback which you can use to control the video.

Comment: If you have to include the player on a Fragment, you should add YouTubePlayerFragment (or YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) to your fragment view by manually calling getChildFragmentManager().add(...).comit() in the Fragment. This is because by using <fragment> tag on Fragment you can't get a reference to the fragment to properly initialize it

Comment: @pedro Loureiro can you please update your answer with some code for how you have handled if there is Fragment in place of the Activity. that will help to other as well.

Comment: This is by far the best answer that I've seen.. i dont need to extend the PlayerFragmnet.. BUT IT really seems like i had to! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem and searched stackoverflow many times. Solution was just Simply extend `Fragment` instead of `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`.

```
public class FragmentTrailers extends Fragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = BuildConfig.YOUTUBE_API;
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
private String url;

YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment_trailers, container, false);

    youTubePlayerView = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerView).commit();

    youTubePlayerView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    return view;
}
}
```

XML Layout file.

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"/>
```