# Youtube Android API NullPointerException Error in Youtube Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, youtube-api, fragment

Basically i'm trying to create youtube fragment. This fragment displays when any List item is selected.
I'm getting NullPointerExpection error. Not exactly sure, what am i doing wrong.

Youtube fragment

```
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Youtube extends Fragment implements OnInitializedListener{
     public static final String API_KEY = "MyKey";
     public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";

     /*public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_fragment);
        YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
           youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);
        }
*/
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
       youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_fragment, container, false);
        }

        private void setContentView(int youtubeFragment) {
            //YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
             //  youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);
               /*Fragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerFragment();
               FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
               FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment, fragment);
               ft.addToBackStack(null);
               ft.commit(); 

               YouTubePlayerFragment youtubeFrag = (YouTubePlayerFragment) fragment;
               youtubeFrag.initialize(API_KEY, this);*/
        }

        @Override
         public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
           YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "onInitializationFailure()", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

        private Context getApplicationContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                boolean wasRestored) {
              if (!wasRestored) {
                    player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                  }
        }
```

youtube_fragments.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Youtube" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Errors

```
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339): Process: com.example.actionbartab, PID: 1339
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at com.example.actionbartab.Youtube.onCreateView(Youtube.java:36)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-18 14:57:36.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use a YouTubePlayerView from a Fragment. As far as I know, this is not how the api should be used (I couldn't make it work this way).

Either use YouTubeBaseActivity and YouTubePlayerView (without fragments) or use your Activity class and include the YouTubePlayerFragment (don't extend it; don't directly add a YouTubePlayerView).

This related question might be useful for you: [NullPointerException on super.onStart()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255465/nullpointerexception-on-super-onstart/25015221#25015221)